# CakePHP CSS not loading on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. After upgrading when I start to configure CakePHP Application, its CSS is not loading.

**I have tried:**

1. enable rewrite module
2. Check file permissions
3. AllowOverride to All in sites-available
4. Read many questions regarding it and Googled alot.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Anything in the Cake or Apache logs ? Any error message on the CSS urls ?

Comment: Nothing in apache and cakephp logs. Not Found 404 error in Firebug Console for css file. But file is present there.

Comment: CSS links are broken if your website is loading - do you have link to your website?

Comment: I have included using $this->Html->css('cake.generic'); and also it is present in webroot/css

Answer (score 0):

Verify your htacces files, may be the probleme comes from there.
I had an issue with css, wich has been resolved by correcting the htacces files from cakephp documentation.